# Why this MD5 result with Salt has "==" in the end of result string?

Tags: java, hash, md5, salt, jasypt

I have java code that use jasypt (Java Simplified Encryption) library:

```
    StandardStringDigester digester = new StandardStringDigester();
    digester.setAlgorithm("MD5");
    digester.setIterations(1);

    FixedStringSaltGenerator saltGenerator = new FixedStringSaltGenerator();
    saltGenerator.setSalt("justAnotherSalt");

    digester.setSaltGenerator(saltGenerator);
    digester.setSaltSizeBytes(5);

    String digest = digester.digest("my_password");

    System.out.println(digest);
```

You can see that I used MD5 algorithm with salt.

The result in console is:

```
I9uMOxDiImtxMXKXkt2EUw==
```

I want to know why there are "==" characters in the end of result string? It's only exist if I used Salt.

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916805/why-base64-encoding-string-have-sign-in-the-last

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StandardStringDigester.digest API says *The result is encoded in BASE64 (default) or HEXADECIMAL and returned as an ASCII String*. In your case this is BASE64

Comment: It's said that in wikipedia: The '==' sequence indicates that the last group contained only 1 byte. What does it mean by the last group?

Comment: base64 converts each group of 3 bytes -> 4 chars. If the last group is 2 bytes the result is padded with '='. If it is 1 byte the result is padded with "==".