# Encryption routine adds %3D to the end of ouput

Tags: php, encryption

I have an encryption that I use for some minor security but I am noticing that the out always seems to have %3D at the end of the encrypted string and I am not sure why.

```
private static function encrypt($str, $key)
{
    $result = null;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        $char = substr($str, $i, 1);
        $keyChar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key)) - 1, 1);
        $char = chr(ord($char) + ord($keyChar));
        $result .= $char;
    }

    return urlencode(base64_encode($result));
}
```

I cannot see anything glaring in there.

When decrypting the strings there are no errors when I manually remove the extra %3D at the end of the string.

so

bnNMTXc0Sjc%3D

AND

bnNMTXc0Sjc

Will both decrypt the same. I just want to clean up the encrypted strings to not have the extra chars at end.

Thanks

Comment: Base64 pads its output with `=`. `=` URL-encoded is `%3D`.

Comment: Why are you not using proper encryption? The `mcrypt_encrypt` function makes it relatively easy, and it is much safer than this function (no offence, but peer-reviewed code written by people who know what they are doing is a lot safer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the URL encode with the = at the end of the base 64 it won't cause an issue [Why does a base64 encoded string have an = sign at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916805/why-base64-encoding-string-have-sign-in-the-last)

Comment: Ah I totally missed that. Is there a way to remove the padding in the encoding or is that a major security issue.

Comment: You can remove with rtrim but ITV won't be valid base 64

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice I will just leave it there as it is only for aesthetics that I was looking to remove it.