# TripleDES returning the "equal" symbol in encrypted data

Tags: c#-4.0, encryption, tripledes

I am trying to Encrypt / Decrypt data to use in the Querystring.

Most of the time, the encrypted data ends with the "equal" symbol '='

The following are some examples of encrypted string

```
 1 - LS07D43u6Hs= 
 2 - oHPgq6hz0A0=  
 3 - 4ugeuARQvXw=   
 abc - gZfrQVAk9Ic=  
 encode me - RfSQYXX1P4MU7LhMsfsG8w==
```

I copied the codes from here and changed a bit.

http://www.deltasblog.co.uk/code-snippets/basic-encryptiondecryption-c/

```
        byte[] inputArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("encode me");
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tripleDES.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abcd123456Idlaaz");
        tripleDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tripleDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tripleDES.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(inputArray, 0, inputArray.Length);
        tripleDES.Clear();


        Response.Write(Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length));
```

I tried to change the Key, PaddingMode, CipherMode, but no luck.  It always return = at the end.  Please help me.

Comment: That's Base64 padding, so it's added by `ToBase64String` not by 3DES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the equal sign at the end isnt beign generated by the encypting algo. 
Its a standard procedure to pad when creating a base 64 encoded string. 
you can find more info at [Why does a base64 encoded string have an = sign at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916805/why-base64-encoding-string-have-sign-in-the-last)

also this ending mechanism is very nicely explained here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: Is it possible that it's going to add "&" sign in the encrypted string?   I am going to use that encrypted string in the QueryString.  So, it must not have & sign.

Comment: the typical solution is to url encode the query string and then use it.. when you wanna read it just url decode it