# C# and SQL Server disagree about whether a string is valid Base64 - which is correct?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, base64

We have the following table on a SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) database:

```
-- irrelevant columns omitted
create table Person
           ( PersonID int,
             Portrait varchar(max) )
```

The `Person.Portrait` column contains Base64 strings encoded from JPG images - this is populated by a third-party system we have no control over. I need to convert this data back to raw bytes so I can display it in a report:

```
select isnull(cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("psn.Portrait"))', 'varbinary(max)'), 0xdeadbeef) as [Portrait]
  from Person psn with (nolock)
 where psn.PersonID = <n>
```

For some rows this is returning valid `varbinary` data, for others it's returning `OxDEADBEEF` (in other words, the result of the XML expression is returning `null`).

However, if I run the following C# code against the rows in the `Person` table that are returning `null` in SQL Server, I get valid JPG images output:

```
var portraitBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Sql.SelectSingleString(
@"select psn.Portrait
    from Person psn with (nolock)
   where psn.PersonID = <n>"));

using (var writer = new FileStream(@"C:\portrait.jpg", FileMode.CreateNew))
{
  writer.Write(portraitBytes, 0, portraitBytes.Length);
}
```

The only differences I can see between the values that are seen as "valid" by SQL Server, versus those that are "invalid", is that the "invalid" ones end with the character `Z`. If I replace this character with `=` then SQL Server is happy.

If I run the above C# code on a Base64 string ending in `Z`, but with that char replaced by `=`, the code runs fine and the resulting outputted image is 1 byte smaller but (apparently) renders identically.

So my questions:

1. Is it valid to end a Base64 string with `Z`?
2. Which one is misbehaving: C# by accepting an invalid Base64 string, or SQL Server by rejecting a valid one?
3. Is it safe to replace `Z` with `=` to allow SQL Server to not puke? In other words, is there a possibility that the resulting bytes will not be valid JPG data?

Comment: i cant help you, but maybe this will help you a little http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916805/why-base64-encoding-string-have-sign-in-the-last

Comment: Belia09 is right, look at that answer and also the wikipedia article mentioned in the comments of one of the answers.

Comment: While I appreciate your attempts to assist, my question is NOT "how does base64 work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Neither, see below.
3. No longer relevant, see below.

After much spelunking I figured that the data in `psn.Portrait` contains a trailing `NUL` (`\0`) character, which is not displayed when running a `select` in SQL Server Management Studio. So every time I copied data from SSMS to test with as a literal, it wouldn't have a trailing `NUL` and hence would decode correctly. Of course, when referencing the actual value in the column, the `NUL` came along for the ride and caused MSSQL to correctly reject the string.

On the C# side, turns out that `Sql.SelectSingleString` helper method has a line in it that says `result.Trim('\0')`. Why it's there I can't fathom, but that explains why C# didn't choke on the `NUL`... it wasn't there to choke on.

Comment: Thankfully, SSMS 2012 *does* support `select`ing strings that contain embedded NUL chars.