# Convert from byte array to StringBase64

Tags: javascript, base64

I have an array with bytes and need them to be in StringBase64 and I am using the following:

```
var base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arrayDigestion)));
console.log('digestionB64_2 .......:' + digestionB64);
```

with the following result:

```
digestionB64_2 .......:6d9310a8df39348ef2bbd8a0f04f65bba64180666848526a4c93e86aa69433e7
```

And I've also used the following code and get the same results no difference whatsoever:

```
function arrayBufferToString(buffer) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }
    return binary;
}
```

As I understand Strings in Base 64 must end with an `=` or `==` characters

Would it be valid if I add those characters manually  at the end or is it valid to have a StringBase64 without them?

Comment: The `=` is used as padding if your data doesn't [perfectly fit into right byte increments.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6916831/371184) Your code is a'okay.

Comment: oooh, got it, thanks