# '=' symbol in Base64

Tags: string, base64

I've looked around a bit and am having trouble finding an explanation for this. I always see the '=' character coming at the end of b64 text (for instance a PGP key). Is '=' in b64 equivalent to the null terminator '\0' in ASCII? Otherwise, what does it represent and why is it always at the end of b64 text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Why does a base64 encoded string have an = sign at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916805/why-does-a-base64-encoded-string-have-an-sign-at-the-end)

Answer (score -1):

Although the answer is indicated in the SO post, however I will give my 5 cents.

This is known as padding. A Base64 string maynot end with one or two '='. It will only be done to pad the string to required length.

SO reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916805/why-does-a-base64-encoded-string-have-an-sign-at-the-end)