# Unexpected token : in JSON at position 603069

Tags: node.js

I receive the below object in my service but when I am parsing this object I get the error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 603069

Code:

```
        var data1 = [];
        // Process a chunk of data. This may be called multiple times.
        req
          .on("data", function(chunk) {
            // Append to buffer
            data1.push(chunk);
          })
          .on("end", function() {
            var buffer = Buffer.concat(data1);
            console.info("Buffer Data Request Body: " + buffer);
            buffer = buffer.toString("utf8");
            var partsOfStr = buffer.split("&");

            //This line gives error
            var obj = JSON.parse(
              decodeURI(buffer.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g, '":"'))
            );
```

Object:

```
{
       "type" : "NewThreadVoice",
       "incidentId": "398115",
       "channel" : "Mobile",
       "data": a huge base 64 string 
       "fileName": "1.aac",
       "contentType" : "aac",
       "contactId" : "954344"
}
```

When I reduce the base64 (value of data) to half it works.

Comment: `=` is a valid character in base64 so it's probably part of your base64 string. When you do `.replace(/=/g, '":"')`, you are potentially replacing part of that string, creating something like `"data": "aacasc":"asdasd",`, which is not valid JSON.

Comment: thnks. It helped

Answer (score 0):

A base64 string is not necessary to contain only one "=" character. This character is used for padding (for more information see [Why does a base64 encoded string have an = sign at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916805/why-does-a-base64-encoded-string-have-an-sign-at-the-end) )

For example, the codification of `home` in base64 is `aG9tZQ==`. Using your code ( `.replace(/=/g, '":"')` ), this will be transformed into `aG9tZQ":"":"`

You should use `.replace(/=+/g, '":"')` for replacing all consecutive `=` chars.