# md5 in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, md5

In BigQuery, I'm using md5 function as:

```
select md5('<<some string>>') as hashed
```

which always returns "==" in the last of the letter like:

```
R7zlx09Yn0hn29V+nKn4CA==
```

Why does '==' always come with it?

Comment: The returned string is base64 encoded I'm pretty sure it is just padding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916805/why-does-a-base64-encoded-string-have-an-sign-at-the-end

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use TO_HEX to get the representation you want as md5 returns `BYTES` and you need strings:

> TO_HEX: Converts a sequence of BYTES into a hexadecimal STRING.
>   Converts each byte in the STRING as two hexadecimal characters in the
>   range (0..9, a..f).

```
select TO_HEX(md5('123456')) as hashed
```

returns:

```
e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
```

Answer (score 3):

The `=` are due to the [base64's padding](https://parsiya.net/blog/2017-08-06-tldr-base64/). Nevertheless and according to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#md5), the output should be bytes, but instead the output is a base64 string. You could check this with the following query:

```
SELECT MD5("Hello World") AS MD5,TO_HEX(MD5("Hello World")) AS BYTES,TO_BASE64(FROM_HEX(TO_HEX(MD5("Hello World")))) as BASE64
```

With the following output:

```
Row |MD5                        |BYTES                              |BASE64  
1   |sQqNsWTgdUEFt6mb5y4/5Q==   |b10a8db164e0754105b7a99be72e3fe5   |sQqNsWTgdUEFt6mb5y4/5Q=
```