# Valid JWT token with wrong Base64 encoding?

Tags: jwt, base64

When I was trying to decode the 2nd part of a JWT token, which should be a base64 encoded string, I found several characters missing in the end:

```
echo "eyJ0ZW5hbnRfaWQiOiJzdXBlcmNoYXJnaW5nIiwiYXVkIjoiIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MH0" | base64 -D
{"tenant_id":"supercharging","aud":"","version":
```

The correct base64 encoded string should be:

```
echo "eyJ0ZW5hbnRfaWQiOiJzdXBlcmNoYXJnaW5nIiwiYXVkIjoiIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MH0K" |
base64 -D
{"tenant_id":"supercharging","aud":"","version":0}
```

So I tried to paste it in the debugger https://jwt.io/, for example:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0ZW5hbnRfaWQiOiJzdXBlcmNoYXJnaW5nIiwiYXVkIjoiIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MH0.oxpfv0W9GYjt2QlG4lqMcoRYdlBTg9_YF6ITGRrxBAQ
```

it's a valid JWT token, and I also tried:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0ZW5hbnRfaWQiOiJzdXBlcmNoYXJnaW5nIiwiYXVkIjoiIiwidmVyc2lvbiI6MH0K.oxpfv0W9GYjt2QlG4lqMcoRYdlBTg9_YF6ITGRrxBAQ
```

it's also a valid JWT token. Is it a bug with jwt.io or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with jwt.io and the shorter string is also fine.

The shorter version (67 characters) is probably just missing a padding character (`=`) to be correct Base64. The length of a Base64 string is supposed to be a multiple of 4 and might be filled up with one or two [padding characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916805/why-does-a-base64-encoded-string-have-an-sign-at-the-end) to reach that size. But JWT uses [Base64Url](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-3) encoding, which does not require padding.

Each 4 Base64(Url) characters encode 3 bytes. On the end of the Base64(Url) string you have the sequence `biI6` which is `n":` after decoding and then `MH0` to encode the rest of the JSON which is `0}`. `M` and the first 2 bits of `H` are decoded to `0` and the last 4 bits  of `H` and the first 4 bits of `0` are decoded to `}`. The remaining 2 bits will be ignored. If you add `K` to the string, you have enough bits for one more byte and get an addional linefeed (LF) character on the end after decoding, which is obviously not needed for a valid JSON. You could also add a `=` instead to satisfy your Base64 decoder.

Comment: Very precise answer, thanks! I also found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916805/why-does-a-base64-encoded-string-have-an-sign-at-the-end which explained the meaning of the tailing `=`.

Comment: @wbsnail thanks. I added a short explanatin about padding to, for completeness.