# Base64 encoding have different values on Windows vs Debian linux

Tags: linux, windows, openssl, base64

I am using OpenSSL to encode base64 string.

On windows:

```
echo -n "1" | openssl.exe base64 
MQo=
```

On Debian:

```
echo -n "1" | openssl base64
MQ==
```

I get `MQo=` from Windows, but `MQ==` from linux.

Does anyone know the reason? and which platform generated the right one?

Answer (score 1):

It may not be OS dependent, according to the explanation given below:
[Why does a base64 encoded string have an = sign at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916805/why-does-a-base64-encoded-string-have-an-sign-at-the-end)

But the example you've provided the data is the same on both OS.

Answer (score 1):

`MQo=` means `0x31 0x0a`, `MQ==` means `0x31`. Windows  `echo` command does not support `-n` argument, reference: [windows echo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo)