# Forming a base64 strings of equal length for any given size file

Tags: java, c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Actually, I require

> A valid Base64 string value that identifies the block. Prior to
>   encoding, the string must be less than or equal to 64 bytes in size.
>
> For a given blob, the length of the value specified for the blockid
>   parameter must be the same size for each block.
>
> Note that the Base64 string must be URL-encoded.

as stated in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-block.

For that, I am converting some C# code to Java. And I am having problem with this line of code

```
//create a blockID from the block number, add it to the block ID list
                      //the block ID is a base64 string
String blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("BlockId{0}",blockNumber.ToString("0000000"))));
```

I have tried below:

```
String str = "BlockId"+blockNumber;
String blockId = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("BlockId"+(blockNumber+"")).getBytes("utf-8"));
```

But, I am not able to understand what "0000000" as a argument to ToString doing and what is its equivalent in Java.

And also how can I fulfil the second condition that length of blockid of each block or chance file should be same in JAVA. As file size can vary.

Comment: What is `blockNumber`? How is it declared in the C# version?

Answer (score 2):

In C#, [`toString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5(v=vs.110).aspx) has several overloaded versions. The one that accepts a `String` parameter uses the `String` to specify the format. In this case, the number will be padded with enough 0s to ensure there are 7 digits. In Java, you can use [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) to get the same behavior. See [the format string documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for details about format string syntax.

Answer (score 2):

In your C# example code `blockNumber.ToString("0000000")` just pads `blockNumber` with leading zeros to a fixed-length string of size 7. You can achieve the same in Java with [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).

To encode this string with the correct Base64 scheme that can be used in URLs, you can use [Base64.getUrlEncoder()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html#getUrlEncoder--) since Java 8.

A complete Java 8 example:

```
long blockNumber = 123;

// left pad block number with zeros to a fixed length of 7
String fixedLengthBlockNumber = String.format("%07d", blockNumber);

// Base64 encode using the "URL and Filename safe Base64 Alphabet"
String blockId = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(fixedLengthBlockNumber.getBytes("utf-8"));
```

The `blockNumber` is just a number you assign to your blocks. It may or may not be derived from the block content itself. If it's derived from the block content (e.g. via [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) checksum), the checksum itself already fulfils the fixed length criterion and you even don't have to pad the number.

Comment: But, the problem with above I am having is that if you give number greater then 7 digit ex "99888877" it will print as it is with error.

Comment: `String.format()` doesn't print anything, it just returns a string. If your number has more digits than the padding length in the format pattern then the number just isn't padded.

Answer (score 0):

The "00000000" parameter tells the Format method to create an 8-digit string with leading 0s. See [this MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048(v=vs.110).aspx)

For the issue with fixed block size, you could fill up with = characters. When you read your data, remove all = characters and then fill up to a length that is multiple-of-3. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080988/why-does-base64-encoding-requires-padding-if-the-input-length-is-not-divisible-b)