# Decoding utf-8 String using python 3.6

Tags: python, utf-8, decoding

I tried to decode the utf-8 string which I encoded successfully but can't figure out how to decode it... 
Actually it's decoded very well, but I just want to concatenate it with like:

```
b = base64.b64decode(a).decode("utf-8", "ignore")
print('Decoding:'+b)
```

as I did in by doing encoding

```
a = str(base64.b64encode(bytes('hasni zinda ha u are my man boy yes u are ', "utf-8")))
print('Encoding :'+a)
```

Whenever i try to do it in the way which i want it gives me the error about :

```
File "C:/Users/…/python/first.py", line 8, in <module>
  b = base64.b64decode(a).decode("utf-8", "ignore")
File "C:\Users\…\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
  return binascii.a2b_base64(s) binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve it?

Comment: That `Incorrect padding` error comes from the base64 part of your code, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080988/why-does-base64-encoding-require-padding-if-the-input-length-is-not-divisible-by I suggest that you break your code into individual function calls instead of call chains—that’ll make it easier to debug and understand.

Comment: Incorrect padding caused by incorrect number of length in string. For base64, length should be divisible by 4. Otherwise, you have to pad with '=' at the end to make it such length. Please find more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding)

Answer (score 10):

Follow-up to my [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352804/decoding-utf-8-string-using-python-3-6#comment-83692457).

You have to reverse the sequence of operation when you decode a [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded string:

```
>>> s = "hasni zinda ha u are my man boy yes u are "
# Encode the Python str into bytes.
>>> b = s.encode("utf-8")
# Base64 encode the bytes.
>>> s_b64 = base64.b64encode(b)
>>> print("Encoding: " + str(s_b64))
Encoding: b'aGFzbmkgemluZGEgaGEgdSBhcmUgbXkgbWFuIGJveSB5ZXMgdSBhcmUg'
```

Now that you have the encoded string, decoding works in reverse order:

```
# Base64 decode the encoded string into bytes.
>>> b = base64.b64decode(s_b64)
# Decode the bytes into str.
>>> s = b.decode("utf-8")
print("Decoding: " + s)
Decoding: hasni zinda ha u are my man boy yes u are
```

For more details, please see the documentation for [`b64encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode) and [`b64decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode), as well as the [Output padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding) section for Base64 (required to ensure that a Base64 encoded string’s length is divisible by 4).

To use your two-liners:

```
>>> a = base64.b64encode(bytes("hasni zinda ha u are my man boy yes u are ", "utf-8"))
>>> print("Encoding:", a)
Encoding: b'aGFzbmkgemluZGEgaGEgdSBhcmUgbXkgbWFuIGJveSB5ZXMgdSBhcmUg'
>>> b = base64.b64decode(a).decode("utf-8")
>>> print("Decoding:", b)
Decoding: hasni zinda ha u are my man boy yes u are
```