# getUrlEncoder/getUrlDecoder proplem padding in Java

Tags: java

I want to encode and decode a string into base64 without padding.

it's correct following code?

```java
    String test = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(test);
    String output = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(test);
```

The lenght without padding always be correct in decoding?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to encode and decode a string variable, you can use the following code:

```java
String s = "test";
String test = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); // dGVzdA
String output = new String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(test), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // test
```

You can get more information about Base64 in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13109632/10951752). There is also a nice [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080988/why-does-base64-encoding-require-padding-if-the-input-length-is-not-divisible-by/18518605#18518605) about padding characters. And I found a short [tutorial](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2020/09/java-8-base64-encoding-and-decoding-with-examples.html) from JavaCodeGeeks:

> By default, encoding pads with the ‘=’ double equal operator if the encoded string length is not met the desired length.
>
> Typically, an encoded string should be multiples of 3 otherwise it will be added with = character.
>
> On the other side, while decoding all extra padded characters will be discarded.
>
> If you do want to be decoded then encode without padding using withoutPadding().
>
> withoutPadding() method helps to skip the padding of the output.
>
> Many developers think that no padding encoded string cannot be decoded back to the original string.
>
> But, it is wrong and [Base64.Decode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html) api provides flexibility to decode back.

Comment: Converting bytes to and from a String without a Charset is not portable across platforms—it will do different things on Windows than on other systems.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. If `getBytes` is called, the default charset of the operating system would be used.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for Base64.Decoder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html) says:

> The Base64 padding character `'='` is accepted and interpreted as the end of the encoded byte data, but is not required.

So any base 64 sequence encoded without padding will be accepted by Base64.Decoder.