# base64 encoded string: can be decoded in PHP but not Java?

Tags: java, php, base64

PHP code that works:

```
$str = "528ABf4cCU5g7zKzLC2t8oze4mstEcWKErar6FbTK2Xo97bu17S8cDmEg5HlbgcLtfvKCVvJ4FnRV3R1iX1TWZIyM7T2352wsb6LUyqFXA03Fz9G6dQmhRrkWpOXAoHeU/H63LKKzcJDhNb3YI2hfsU20BcT0qkk74XKneC7D91OKY=";
echo strlen(base64_decode($str));
```

That outputs 130.

Java code that doesn't work:

```
String demo = "528ABf4cCU5g7zKzLC2t8oze4mstEcWKErar6FbTK2Xo97bu17S8cDmEg5HlbgcLtfvKCVvJ4FnRV3R1iX1TWZIyM7T2352wsb6LUyqFXA03Fz9G6dQmhRrkWpOXAoHeU/H63LKKzcJDhNb3YI2hfsU20BcT0qkk74XKneC7D91OKY=";
System.out.println(java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(demo).length);
```

This throws:

> "Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.

How can I make the base64 encoded string that PHP likes decodable by Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That `demo` input is incorrectly [padded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080988/why-does-base64-encoding-require-padding-if-the-input-length-is-not-divisible-by); it should end in `==` instead of `=`.

You could use a more lenient decoder like Guava's `BaseEncoding`.

Alternatively, since padding is optional in Base64, you could just strip any trailing `=` characters before decoding with `java.util.Base64`.